# Obtener la diferencia de horas entre dos fechas desde 2 Inputs tipo Datetime en JavaScript, Onchange?

Tags: javascript, datetime, diff

necesito ayuda para Obtener las horas transcurridas entre dos fechas desde 2 Inputs tipo Datetime que sea Onchange, en JS

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="fecha_inicio" value="" />
<input type="datetime-local" id="fecha_final" value="" />
<input type="text" id="horas" />
```

De antemano Muchas Gracias!